# remove lower grade duplicates

Tags: pandas, duplicates

```
 dupli = file_copy[file_copy.duplicated(['Course Code'], keep=False)].reset_index()
        cont = 0
        rows_to_delete = []
        print(dupli)

        for i in range(int(len(dupli)/2)):
            if dupli.loc[cont,'Grade'] > dupli.loc[cont+1,'Grade']:
                rows_to_delete.append(dupli.loc[cont+1,'index'])
            else:
                rows_to_delete.append(dupli.loc[cont,'index'])
            cont += 2

        file_copy.drop(index=rows_to_delete, inplace=True)
        file_copy.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Here i have data for repeat course for students i need remove lower grade attempt and keep higher grade one

Comment: `sort_values` and then `drop_duplicates`, which will keep only the highest/lowest depending whether you ascending/descending sort or keep the first/last in the drop

Answer (score 0):

First, `sort_values` by `['Course Code', 'Grade']` then `drop_duplicates` and set the `keep='last'`.